# Springboot NoSuchMethodException with log4j async log

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

The below error occurs while the application starting.

```
AsyncLogger error handling event seq=15, value='org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEvent@5549c0e2': java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocatorUtil.get java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocatorUtil.getCurrentStackTrace() Ljava/util/Deque;
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:112)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:97)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent.getThrownProxy (Log4j LogEvent.java:629)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.MutableLogEvent.initFrom(MutableLogEvent.java:100)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerConfigDisruptor.lambda$static$2 (Async LoggerConfigDisruptor.java:156)
at com.lmax.disruptor.RingBuffer.translateAndPublish (RingBuffer.java:971)
at com.lmax.disruptor.RingBuffer.tryPublishEvent(RingBuffer.java:523)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerConfigDisruptor.tryEnqueue (AsyncLoggerConfigDisruptor.java:378)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerConfig.logToAsync Delegate (AsyncLoggerConfig.java:152)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerConfig.log(AsyncLoggerConfig.java:133)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:604)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:98)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger.actualAsyncLog (AsyncLogger.java:488)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEvent.execute(RingBufferLogEvent.java:156)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEventHandler.onEvent (RingBufferLogEventHandler.java:51)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEventHandler.onEvent (RingBufferLogEventHandler.java:29)
at com.Imax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:129)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
AsyncLogger error handling event seq=15, value='org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.MutableLogEvent@1d5d0e75': java.lang.NullPointerException: null java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerConfigDisruptor$Log4jEventWrapperHandler.onEvent (AsyncLoggerConfigDisruptor.java:112) at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerConfigDisruptor$Log4j EventWrapperHandler.onEvent (AsyncLoggerConfigDisruptor.java:98)
at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:129)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```